# Reusing code in php modules without sharing global namespace

Tags: php, wordpress, namespaces

I can't seem to figure out to achieve the following result. 
Important: this should work down to php 5.3

Ok, so imagine a situation: you develop a number of php modules, for example WordPress plugins, that are to be run on single setup but do not communicate or know about each other. But some (quite large) parts of codebase are the same and can be reused. How can I achieve the result, when all my modules have "inside of them" this shared library, scoped to each module and not causing conflicts in global space?
For example, see the following:

main.php (some host app, like WordPress)

```
<?php

require('plugins/first-module/first.php');
require('plugins/second-module/second.php');

$first = new Project1\App();
$first->go();

$second = new Project2\App();
$second->go();

?>
```

first.php (first module)

```
<?php

namespace Project1;

require('shared.php');

use CoreLib\Util\Logger\Log;

class App {
    public function go() {
        $logger = new Log();

        $logger->say();
    }
}
```

second.php (second module)

```
<?php

namespace Project2;

require('shared.php');

use CoreLib\Util\Logger\Log;

class App {
    public function go() {
        $logger = new Log();

        $logger->say();
    }
}
```

shared.php (shared lib)

```
<?php

namespace CoreLib\Util\Logger;

class Log {
    public function say() {
        echo 'It works!';
    }
}
```

Right now I have an error, obviously, because of re-declaring Log class.
Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe use Aliasing? `use CoreLib\Util\Logger\Log as Project1Logger;` Should work from PHP 5.3.0. http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: Hello, thanks, this indeed makes sense, but it works only if I change require to require_once in each module, so the first loaded module will declare Log class in that namespace, and all others will use it's version. Which will not work for my case unfortunately, as these modules might update at different times and newer modules may end up using older version of shared library.